# Apache dynamic aliases 

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, alias, dynamic

I've got LAMP setup on a VM that I use for multiple projects. My document root is a /www and I create a folder for each project within it.

```
/www/project1-name/
/www/project2-name/
```

I access them in my browser like this:

```
http://dev.vm/project-name/
```

I'd like to move my htaccess and index files to a public folder within a project, so they match their production setup more accurately.

```
/www/project-name/public/
```

...but still access them with the same url as above. How can I get Apache configured to look for public/ folders as document roots for each of my projects?

Note: I understand I can create hosts and vhost entries for each project to have it's own document root, but I'm trying to to avoid that - because I plan on using a similar setup on my remote server to house multiple projects at a subdomain called 'demo'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go one step further with mod_alias and use the [AliasMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch) directive. Should work the same as EightbitTony's solution, but give you the extra regex power.

I did a bit of testing and this looks like it should do it.

```
AliasMatch ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*) /www/$1/public/$2
```

Comment: Nice, hadn't realised it was there, like that solution.

Comment: Could you help with the regex pattern? I'm trying `([^\/]+)` but it's not working.

Comment: I edited the answer with what I think should work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to do any re-writing, don't you just want some good old fashioned Alias statements?

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html,

```
Description: Maps URLs to filesystem locations
Syntax:      Alias URL-path file-path|directory-path
Context:     server config, virtual host
Status:      Base
Module:      mod_alias
```

So,

```
Alias /project-name/  /some/path/to/project-name/public/
Alias /project-name2/ /some/path/to/project-name2/public/
Alias /project-3/     /another/totally/different/path/public/
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it dynamically with some specific conditional logic? So I won't have to add a new vhosts entry for every new project.

Comment: It's not a vhost, it's an alias.  You only have to add one line to your apache config per project.  I'm sure it is possible to use re-write to do it dynamically, but it's overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the apache [dynamically configured mass virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html) documentation. It doesn't sound like you have huge numbers of vhost so the `VirtualDocumentRoot` and related configuration directives will probably do what you want e.g.

```
 VirtualDocumentRoot /www/%2/public
```

which would map to `/www/project-name/public`. The `%n` parameter is [interpolated](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#interpol) from the URL with %0 being the whole, %1 the first part etc.